# Opening Arc Menu Gnome shell extension with super key and now window placement won't work

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell-extension

Ubuntu 18.04 supports super key and arrow key combinations to snap windows to either side of the display. However, after installing Arc Menu from Gnome Shell Extensions and configuring the super key to open that menu, this window placement function doesn't work any more. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Arc Menu overrides all Super key configurations, including <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, etc. (except <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to logout).

The best solution at this point is to change the Arc Menu hotkey in the extension settings to "Right Super" or "undefined", which allows the left super to continue operating the functions defined in gnome settings.